# How to type static property on React Class

Tags: javascript, reactjs, flowtype

I am trying to type a static property on a React Class to use it type safe in a higher order component.

My React class definition looks like this:

```
type ReactComponentClass<DP, P, S> =
    | Class<React$Component<DP, P, S>>
    | ((props: P) => ?React$Element<any>);
```

My first try was

```
type ComponentClassWithStaticPropery<DP,P,S> = ReactComponentClass<DP, P, S>  & {
        staticProp: boolean,
    }
```

This failed like this:

```
    71:                     <Component
                            ^ React element `Component`. Expected React component instead of any member of intersection type
    54:     return ({ Component, ...outerProps }: Props): React$Element<*> => (
                    ^^^^^^^^^ intersection
    Member 1:
    11: type RelayContainer = ReactComponentClass<*, *, *> & {
                                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ type application of polymorphic type: type `ReactComponentClass`
    Error:
    56:             Container={Component}
                                ^^^^^^^^^ intersection. This type is incompatible with
    8:     | ((props: P) => ?React$Element<any>);
                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ function type
    Member 1:
        11: type RelayContainer = ReactComponentClass<*, *, *> & {
                                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ type application of polymorphic type: type `ReactComponentClass`
    Error:
        8:     | ((props: P) => ?React$Element<any>);
                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ function type. Callable signature not found in
        11: type RelayContainer = ReactComponentClass<*, *, *> & {
                                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ statics of React$Component
    Member 2:
        11: type RelayContainer = ReactComponentClass<*, *, *> & {
                                                                ^ object type
    Error:
        8:     | ((props: P) => ?React$Element<any>);
                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ function type. Callable signature not found in
        11: type RelayContainer = ReactComponentClass<*, *, *> & {
                                                                ^ object type
    Member 2:
    11: type RelayContainer = ReactComponentClass<*, *, *> & {
                                                            ^ object type
    Error:
    71:                     <Component
                            ^ React element `Component`. Expected React component instead of
    11: type RelayContainer = ReactComponentClass<*, *, *> & {
                                                            ^ object type
```